# Getting warning while opening Excel file after writing a table to it using PHP

Tags: php, excel

I have the following code which writes a table to Excel file. Once The file gets downloaded but while opening it, getting warning

> The file format and Extension of file.xls do not match. The file could
>   be corrected or unsafe. Unless you trust its source don't open it.

How to resolve this issue?

```
    header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name".date("d_m_Y_H_i_s").".xls");
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");

    ob_clean(); 

    // $res in next line will have a table which I get after processing. 

    $row = $res->getRowAssoc(); 

    $heading = false;
    while ($row != null)
    {
        if(!$heading) {
            for ($ii = 0; $ii < $res->getColumnCount(); $ii++)
            {
                $field_name = $res->getColumnName($ii);
                $field_names[$ii] = $util->get_mls_text($field_name);
            }
            echo implode("\t", $field_names) . "\r\n";   
        }
    $heading = true;

    echo implode("\t", $row) . "\r\n"; 

    $row = $res->getRowAssoc(); 
   }
```

Comment: It looks like your sending a Tab delimited file? xls files are stored in a   binary format. You want CSV or potentially xlsx (which is the xml format) if you format it as such

Comment: @NickSlash Basically I have a table, and I have to write that table to excel file. This is the requirement.

Comment: Easiest fix, change the content-type to `text/csv` and the file extension to `.CSV`. Alternatively there are modules available in PHP that can write Excel/Spreadsheet files, XLSXWriter for example but I've never used it so can't help any further with that.